# Make continuous scrolling default when viewing PDF in Edge microsoft windows 10

Tags: windows-10, pdf, scrolling, microsoft-edge, default-settings

I know if you select "Page View" then "continuous Scrolling ON" from the options you can see the PDF file scroll correctly and most of the times when you open that same file it will maintain the setting. Although every single time I open a new file this setting is OFF. isn't there just a simple way to ENABLE default continuous scrolling default globally for ever and ever I mean why doesn't Microsoft retain such a simple setting! Its driving me mad. I tried many PDF files many different times, it will seldom work as supposed to.

Microsoft windows 10 Edge up to date, enterprise automatic updates bla bla bla, if you need more details please ask.

Comment: Mine is always On by default. Strange. Perhaps check Windows integrity using [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).